# Kernel not found when booting a 16.04 USB on HP Pavilion g6

Tags: boot, kernel, live-usb

I created a live USB from the Ubuntu 16 AMD64 iso using Startup Disk Creator.

But every time I try to boot from the USB, it shows the error

```
vesamenu.c32: not a COM32R image.
```

I have an HP pavilion g6 with an Intel i3 64 bit processor. What do I do? Is ubuntu 16 not compatible with my laptop version?

Comment: sorry to say I don't have any experience with Startup Disk Creator but I have always had success with Rufus if you have the availability of a  Windows machine.. I'm sure someone where will have a solution using Ubuntu though :D

Comment: I got a COM32R error from the 16.04 startup media created on a 14.04 system with startup disk creator, but when the media was created from the same ISO on a 16.04 system with startup disk creator, it worked.  Try dd or rufus too.

Comment: There is an answer suggesting replacing the vesamenu.c32 file here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/85254/cannot-boot-from-usb-disk-with-not-a-com32r-image-error . This worked for me